# MVC login form submit hangs without hitting code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, iis-express

I have an .NET Core MVC application which uses the .NET Identity framework. This was all working perfectly (and had been for 18 months) until recently.

When running the project locally, using IIS Express, the submission of the log in form just hangs in Chrome. The grey spinning wheel appears on the Chrome tab but nothing happens. I have added a breakpoint to the code for the login page (it's a scaffolded MVC Razor Page) but this breakpoint is never hit.

The live version of my website works as expected and when running locally in Firefox, it also works without issue and the breakpoint is hit. To me, this seems to be an issue with Chrome or maybe IIS Express?

I've tried:

- Incognito mode in Chrome.
- Clearing cookies and cached object.
- Running the project in both Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2019.
- Restarting my PC.
- Restarting VS and Chrome.

Below is my code and HTML for the login page. As previously stated, this was scaffolded using Visual Studio so most of it is standard stuff, apart from the changes required to use AWS Cognito as my user store. None of this code has changed recently either.

Login.cshtml

```
@page
@model LoginModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Log in";
}

<div class="container">
    <h2>@ViewData["Title"]</h2>
    <hr />
    @if (Model.ModelState.ErrorCount > 0)
    {
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="alert alert-danger"></div>
    }
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <section>
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Username"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Username" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label asp-for="Input.Password"></label>
                        <input asp-for="Input.Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            <label asp-for="Input.RememberMe">
                                <input asp-for="Input.RememberMe" />
                                @Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Input.RememberMe)
                            </label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Log in</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p>
                            <a asp-page="./ForgotPassword">Forgot your password?</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
}
```

Login.cshtml.cs

```
using Amazon.AspNetCore.Identity.Cognito;
using Amazon.Extensions.CognitoAuthentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;
using Serilog;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TAP.Web.Filters;

namespace TAP.Web.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public class LoginModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly UserManager<CognitoUser> userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<CognitoUser> signInManager;
        private readonly ILogger logger;

        public LoginModel(
            UserManager<CognitoUser> userManager,
            SignInManager<CognitoUser> signInManager,
            ILogger logger)
        {
            this.userManager = userManager;
            this.signInManager = signInManager;
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

        public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

        [TempData]
        public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

        public class InputModel
        {
            [Required]
            [Display(Name = "Username or Email")]
            public string Username { get; set; }

            [Required]
            [DataType(DataType.Password)]
            public string Password { get; set; }

            [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
            public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
            }

            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");
            // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme).ConfigureAwait(false);
            ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        }

        [TestFilter]
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = await signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Username, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
                var user = await this.userManager.FindByIdAsync(Input.Username);

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    logger.Information($"User logged in ({Input.Username}).");
                    return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
                }
                else if (result.IsCognitoSignInResult())
                {
                    if (result is CognitoSignInResult cognitoResult && cognitoResult.RequiresPasswordChange)
                    {
                        switch (user.Status)
                        {
                            case "FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD":
                                logger.Warning($"User password needs to be changed ({Input.Username}).");
                                return RedirectToPage("./ChangePassword", new { username = Input.Username, required = true });
                            case "RESET_REQUIRED":
                                logger.Warning($"User password needs to be reset ({Input.Username})");
                                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Your password requires resetting. Please check your emails for the reset password link.");
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                }

                return Page();
            }

            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
            return Page();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are probably encountering a infinite loop of redirects on Chrome. Some browsers are more sensitive to this then others.

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem using localhost and traced it down to the datatype used for the password field.  If I removed "[DataType(DataType.Password)]", then it doesn't hang any more, although the password field is exposed.

```
        [Required]
        //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
```

I think Chrome detects that your field is a password type and is trying to prompt to update or save the password in your Chrome account password list.  The browser is intercepting and hanging for some reason.  When you remove the DataType decoration, then Chrome doesn't see it as a password type and sends the message on to the server.

I noted that it only hangs Chrome when you either populate an empty password field or completely change the whole password.  It seems to work OK if you modify (add/change/delete some characters) the password without replacing the whole thing.

It only started happening to me recently as well.  Was there a Chrome update that broke password storage for localhost maybe?  I'm sorry I don't have a definitive answer yet, but maybe we can work together to figure it out.

I would have posted this as a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have 50 Reputation yet.